# Better options to save site activity

Tags: java, mysql, database-performance, mysql-5.7, amazon-aurora

I have a sit that over time increased his visitors per hour.
One of the first things I'm doing is to log that use activity (ip, page and action) in a table by simple insert into to table.
The problem is that after that insert there is commit which enforce the binlog data to be written to disk (flush log IO).

This of course causes unwanted bottleneck on put stress to the disks.

Would love to hear your 2cents how to tune it.

I was thinking on 2 option:

1. Cache the activity in the app side, and bulk insert every X time/inserts. The downside is potential data loss in crash scenario.
2. Use mongo/couchbase for this. The downside is it will cause an headache when I will want to join that table with MySQL Tables

Answer (score 0):

```
sync_binlog = OFF
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_doublewrite = OFF
```

Warning:  each has drawbacks.

Alternatives:

- Batch the actions into a single transaction..
- Don't log immediately; instead scrape the web server log file every 10 minutes (or whatever), gather it all together into a few `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` statements.